# Custom help in Rad Studio 10.4

Tags: delphi, rad-studio, delphi-10.4-sydney, help-system, c++builder-10.4-sydney

Is there a way to add my own custom help to the help menu in RAD Studio 10.4?  Under the menu options "Help" | "Third-party help", several of the third party libraries I use have added help for their products.  Is there any way I can add my own help reference material there?

Answer (score 0):

They are listed in the registry under:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Embarcadero\BDS\21.0\Help\HtmlHelp1Files

e.g. on my computer the entry for Indy is:

"Indy Help"   REG_SZ   "c:\delphi\delphi_10_4\help\Doc\Indy10.chm"

Alternatively a plugin can use the Open Tools API to add a menu item as described in the description of [Third-Party Help Menu Item](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/Third-Party_Help_Menu_Item_(Delphi)) in the Embarcadero DocWiki.